# Post command error using Solr: argument list too long

Tags: post, solr, runtime-error

I'm trying to add documents to a specific core that I have created before with this command:

```
./solr create -c kba_oct_2011
```

Than I add the schema using `curl` utility:

```
curl http://localhost:8983/solr/kba_oct_2011/schema -X POST -H 'Content-type:application/json' --data-binary '{
    "add-field" : {
        "name":"title",
        "type":"text_general",
    "indexed":true,
        "stored":true
    },
    "add-field" : {
        "name":"description",
        "type":"text_general",
    "indexed":true,
        "stored":true
    },
    "add-field" : {
        "name":"date",
        "type":"date",
    "indexed":true,
        "stored":true
    }
}'
```

And in the end I'm trying to add documents using `post` command:

```
./post -c kba_oct_2011 /home/IPA/IPA_ws/Dataset_news_KBA/2011/10_October/*.xml
```

In the directory `/home/IPA/IPA_ws/Dataset_news_KBA/2011/10_October/` there are 72.420 files and when I execute the command I have this error:

```
-bash: ./post: Argument list too long
```

Someone can I help me?

Thanks!

Comment: Here it is! @MatsLindh

Answer (score 0):

This occurs beacuse your expanded argument list expands command line input limit.
Use xargs to provide argument list to your post command.